# How to Search and filter "&" sign?

Tags: oracle

I need to search for string and extract row data.
In particular, the string has a special character (& sign). How to filter those kinds of strings.

```
select DISTINCT d.name
from table d
where d.name in ('BUHARY & COMPANY (PVT) LTD','K S KUMARAN')
```

Comment: I assume this didn't work for you because you are using SQL\*Plus or something similar, where SQL\*Plus sees the ampersand first, and it interprets it as a marker for a substitution variable. You can fix that by turning off that interpretation - either `set define off` or perhaps set the "define" character to something other than ampersand.

Comment: A string is a string. There is nothing you have to change. If this doesn't work, then your tool that you use to run the statement is getting in your way. You may have to use `set define off`

Comment: can you plz share the ```set define off``` query with my code

Comment: The `set` command is not part of the query. Are you using SQL\*Plus? That is a piece of software that communicates with the database, but it is not part of the database. It runs on your "client" computer. It has its own scripting language, which supports the `set` command, substitution variables, etc. Simply issue the `set define off` command, on a line by itself (no need for semicolon to terminate it either) **before** you run your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your query on sqlplus, keep in mind that `&` is a special character reserved for variables.

Example

```
SQL> create table my_test ( c1 varchar2(100) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'Hello & Goodbye' ) ;
Enter value for goodbye: ^C
```

Above, sqlplus stops the execution of the insert because it has found the character ampersand. It asks me to enter the value for that variable. To avoid this, I need to tell sqlplus that I am going to use & as a normal string, for that I have the option define

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'Hello & Goodbye' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from my_test where c1 like '%&%' ;

C1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello & Goodbye

SQL>
```

If you use another tool, like Toad or Sql Developer, remember to apply the set define off before

Example with Toad

[image]

Comment: "Above, Oracle stops the execution..." Strictly speaking, that's not right. "Oracle" usually means "the database". The "execution" definitely means in the database. Rather, SQL\*Plus does the "stopping" and that happens before the query is ever sent to the database for execution. I assume you understand all this, but the way you wrote it will still be confusing for those (like the OP) who don't know all of this already.

Comment: Hi @mathguy , you are right, I meant sqlplus. I edited the answer. :)